# XQuery to retrieve values from child nodes of an element node having name changes for every XML record

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, xslt-2.0, xquery-3.0

XML Response payload as below

```
<root>
 <_1>
  <expand>description,lead,url,projectKeys</expand>
  <name>ABC</name>
  <id>12631</id>
</_1>
<_2>
  <expand>description,lead,url,projectKeys</expand>
  <name>XYZ</name>
  <id>12632</id>
</_2>
<_3>
  <expand>description,lead,url,projectKeys</expand>
  <name>JKL</name>
  <id>12634</id>
 </_3>
</root>
```

Here <_1>,<_2>,<_3> can increase sequentially depends on total count of XML records.

My requirements are to write an XQuery

1. To identify total count of values in Element nodes (For eg:- 50 i.e last node is <_50>)
2. Iterate thru all element nodes till 50 (for instance) and pull its corresponding child nodes (for example : expand,name,id)

   I had a similar XML response payload, where instead of sequential increase in the element node values (<_1>,<_2>,<_3> ) , it has a fixed name (entries) to all element nodes . (Example below) and I wrote an XQuery to retrieve the values from its child nodes (see below).

   ```
    <root>
     <entries>
     <added>1534815831000</added>
     <updated>1534815831000</updated>
     </entries>
    <entries>
     <added>1534815832000</added>
     <updated>1534815832000</updated>
     </entries>
     </root>
   ```

XQuery was

```
 let $entries := /root/entries
  return
  for $entry in $entries
  return
    <entries>
     {
    <added>{data($entry/added)}</added>,
    <updated>{data($entry/updated)}</updated>
     }
    </entries>
```

Challenges are

a) When the element node name changes with every record

b)Iteration through all element nodes

Any valuable suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what the desired output is. Or are you just having trouble limiting to the first 50 elements when the element names are all different?

Answer (score 0):

You could select the first 50 elements with a predicate filter: `/root/*[1 to 50]`

You can also use a [positional variable](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xquery-31-20170321/#dt-positional-variable) when iterating through the set of `entry` elements, a `where` clause in your FLWOR to restrict to the first 50, and copy all of the `$entry/*` child elements instead of reconstructing them:

```
for $entry at $i in /root/*
where $i <= 50
return
 element { $entry/local-name() } { 
   $entry/name 
 }
```

Comment: Desired output is <_1><name>ABC</name></_1>
Likewise for <_2> ,<_3>...till the end limit;  it should be in an iterative manner. End limit should also be determined.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the count of entries is just `count(/root/*)`.

Copying the first 50 entries is just `subsequence(/root/*, 1, 50)`.

Copying the first 50 entries while retaining only the `name` child element is

```
for $e in subsequence(/root/*, 1, 50)
return element{local-name($e)}{$e/name}
```

Comment: It works. However , as name and id are also child elements of the same parent element node , I need to retain that as well. For that , I wrote that Xquery which returns (all child values of 'name' then all child values of 'id') and it's not an expected result. Desired output as first child value of 'name' then first child value of 'id'.2nd child value of 'name' then 2nd child value of 'id'. X Query is :
    for $entry at $i in /root/*
    return element{local-name($entry)}{$entry/name},
    for $entry at $i in /root/*
    return element{local-name($entry)}{$entry/self}

Comment: This kind of transformation, where you retain most of the data from the source document and make a few changes, is actually much easier to do in XSLT than XQuery. Alternatively, consider XQuery Update.